# Select First Row of Every Group in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables .

1-> SM_Employee

> ```
>  (1) employeeid   
>  (2) roleid
>  (3) storeid
> ```

2-> SM_SalesRepWorkflow

> ```
>  (1) workflowid
>  (2) Salesrepid   foreign key to employeeid
>  (3) QuantityAssigned
>  (4) QuantityLeft
>  (5) month 
>  (6) year
> ```

By these tables I need to select first row of every SalesRep Details from   SM_SalesRepWorkflow order by SalesRepId for CurrentMonth and CurrentYear.

Example

Workflowid   SalesRepId  QuantityAssigned  QuantityLeft  Month  Year

> WF_101   :   EMP_101  :      100        :     90      :   May :   2013
>   WF_101   :   EMP_102  :      100        :     100     :   May :   2013
>   WF_101   :   EMP_103  :      100        :     80      :   May :   2013
>   WF_102   :   EMP_101  :      100        :     70      :   May :   2013

So result i want is

> WF_101   :   EMP_101  :      100        :     90      :   May :   2013
>   WF_101   :   EMP_102  :      100        :     100     :   May :   2013
>   WF_101   :   EMP_103  :      100        :     80      :   May :   2013

So There can be many Workflow for a SalesRep. 
But i want the first one for every SalesRep for current month and year.

Comment: What is your sort order?

Comment: Order By SalesRepId,WorkflowId and for every SalesRepId i want the first row of that SalesRepId.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM(SELECT workflowid, salesRepId, quantityAssigned,
              quantityLeft, month, year
              , ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (PARTITION BY salesRepId
                          ORDER BY workflowid) AS rownumber
         FROM sm_salesRepWorkflow)
 WHERE rownumber = 1;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dccca/1)**

Comment: Just looking for this
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding the question so if I'm off I'll edit it after, but it looks like you want to do something like `SELECT * FROM SM_SalesRepWorkflow WHERE Workflowid = latest` where latest is the id of the workflow. Perhaps you can determine the latest outside of the query and bring that in instead of doing it from the query?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please avoid doing this lest your posts will get flagged.

Comment: I gave an answer I thought addressed the question but also asked OP to reclarify. It seemed wasteful to post a comment expressing confusion and then an overly certain answer.