# SQL Query to fetch 300k latest records from 10 different groups equally

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which may contain around 3 million data, I need query to fetch around 300k data with status 'inactive' say all regions having 30k data and export into csv file.

```
select Id, Name, region, status, creationdate 
from Organization 
where status = 'inactive' 
group by region
having count = 30000
order by creationdate desc;
```

Does this query fetch the latest data in all regions or need to be fine tuned?

Comment: The query will not run you will get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select First Row of Every Group in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529701/select-first-row-of-every-group-in-sql)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this one:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (select Id, Name, region, status, creationdate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REGION ORDER BY creationdate DESC) as ROW_NUM 
        from Organization 
       where status='inactive')
WHERE ROW_NUM <= 30000
```

Comment: I have run query and getting same region data not distinct regions