# Oracle 11g - select only one row for each town in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, unique

I have a table with 300K records, but only ~100 unique town names.  I need sql to return 1 row for each individual town name.  Table structure:

| UNIQUE_ID | STREET_NUMBER | STREET_NAME | STREET_TYPE | TOWN | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UID01 | 11 | TROY | STREET | ASHFIELD | 2017 |
| UID02 | 13 | ABED | ROAD | ASHFIELD | 2017 |
| UID03 | 2 | FRANK | COURT | EMERTON | 2021 |
| UID04 | 8 | DENNIS | GROVE | SACKVILLE | 2028 |
| UID05 | 97 | MAC | CRESCENT | SACKVILLE | 2028 |
| UID06 | 102 | CHARLIE | WALK | SACKVILLE | 2028 |
| UID07 | 70 | DEE | BOULEVARD | WINDSOR | 2033 |
| UID08 | 27 | POPPY | STREET | WINDSOR | 2033 |
| UID09 | 33 | ALLY | WAY | BARGO | 2315 |
| UID10 | 48 | ELS | AVENUE | BARGO | 2315 |

I'm trying to get the data returned to be something like:

| UNIQUE_ID | STREET_NUMBER | STREET_NAME | STREET_TYPE | TOWN | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UID01 | 11 | TROY | STREET | ASHFIELD | 2017 |
| UID03 | 2 | FRANK | COURT | EMERTON | 2021 |
| UID04 | 8 | DENNIS | GROVE | SACKVILLE | 2028 |
| UID07 | 70 | DEE | BOULEVARD | WINDSOR | 2033 |
| UID09 | 33 | ALLY | WAY | BARGO | 2315 |

Don't care which record is returned for each town name, but need one record for each town.

I've trawled through various similar posts but can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I'm able to select each individual town name using this:

```
select min(TOWN) keep (dense_rank first order by rownum) TOWN
from ADDRESS_TABLE group by TOWN;
```

But not sure how to get the other attached data to return as well.

Help please?

Comment: What is the logic behind which single record for each town gets selected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select First Row of Every Group in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529701/select-first-row-of-every-group-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about which one to take, then take any of them (e.g. first by `unique_id`):

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT unique_id,
              street_number,
              street_name,
              street_type,
              town,
              zip,
              ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY town ORDER BY unique_id) rn
         FROM address_table)
SELECT unique_id,
       street_number,
       street_name,
       street_type,
       town,
       zip
  FROM temp
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Perfect, this did exactly the trick - thanks heaps Littlefoot!