# sql combine records based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which holds 5 columns. I than wrote a basic sql statment which group all columns (to make sure there are no duplicates records).

```
select flag, year, month, name, max(description) description
from table1
group by flag, year, month, name 
order by year
```

**Sql output result:**

| flag | year | month | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | 2017 | 2 | name1 | random description11 |
| Yes | 2017 | 2 | name1 | random description112 |
| No | 2018 | 7 | name4 | random description44 |
| Yes | 2022 | 4 | name8 | random description999 |
| No | 2022 | 4 | name8 | random description999 |

**Issue:**
I am getting 5 reocrds, however i want them to combine into 3 records.

1st & 2nd records are the same bc they have the same `year, month, & name`; therefor it should be combined into one records and show row with `flag` column value is `yes`.

3rd record is has only one record so just show that.

4th & 5th records are the same bc they have the same `year, month, & name`; therefor it should be combined into one records and show row with `flag` column value is `yes`.

**What i need:**

| flag | year | month | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 2017 | 2 | name1 | random description112 |
| No | 2018 | 7 | name4 | random description44 |
| Yes | 2022 | 4 | name8 | random description999 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select First Row of Every Group in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529701/select-first-row-of-every-group-in-sql)

Comment: @astentx stop flagging this post as duplicate... solution `ROW_NUMBER()` didnt worked for me. please re-read my post, maybe that will help

Comment: "didn't work" provides no information about an actual issue. It actually does https://dbfiddle.uk/SYld_5zZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX` with `KEEP`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(flag) AS flag,
       year,
       month,
       name,
       MAX(description) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY flag) AS description
FROM   table1
GROUP BY year, month, name 
ORDER BY year;
```

or the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT flag,
       year,
       month,
       name,
       description
FROM   (
  SELECT flag,
         year,
         month,
         name,
         description,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY year, month, name ORDER BY flag DESC, description DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table1
)
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER BY year;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use RWO_NUMBR to filter the wanted rows

```
WITH CTE1 as (
select flag, year, month, name, max(description) description
from table1
group by flag, year, month, name 
order by year), 
CTE2 AS (SELECT "flag", "year", "month", "name", "description"
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "year" ORDER BY "flag" DESC) rn
  FROM CTE1)
  SELECT "flag", "year", "month", "name", "description" FROM CTE2
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT flag, year, month, name, MAX(description) AS description
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY flag, year, month, name
)
SELECT flag, year, month, name, description
FROM cte
ORDER BY year;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?