# Oracle join with first row from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables where I want to join the tables by id. But my problem is that in one table I get multiple results for a specific id and I only want the row with the newest date.

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.ID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN (TABLE_C subquery where I want only the row where DATECOLUMN has the newest date)
```

I can get the row in a single query like this `SELECT * FROM TABLE_C ORDER BY DATECOLUM DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`

But I have not managed to construct a query where I also am able to join the results with the subquey

I have tried googeling and even got some help on discord, but was not able to get any working soultion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select First Row of Every Group in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529701/select-first-row-of-every-group-in-sql)

Comment: What is the issue with just `where` clause? `select ... where <join conditions> order by ... fetch first row only` Or use subquery that select the first row per group and then do join with that subquery. It depends on cardinalities of both datasets and predicate selectivity, but for bulk processing the latter approach is generally more performant then correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define MAX date per IDs in your subquery. This will result in 1 row per ID so you can join it on ID columns:

```sql
SELECT      a.ID, b.A_NAME, c.A_DATE 
FROM        tbl_a a 
LEFT JOIN   tbl_b b ON (b.ID = a.ID)
LEFT JOIN   (Select ID, Max(A_DATE) "A_DATE" From tbl_c Group By ID) c ON(c.ID = a.ID)
```

... test with some dummy sample data

```sql
WITH
    tbl_a AS
        (   Select LEVEL "ID" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3   ),
--          ID
--  ----------
--           1
--           2
--           3

    tbl_b AS 
        (   Select LEVEL "ID", 'Name ' || LEVEL "A_NAME" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3 ),
--          ID A_NAME                                       
--  ---------- ---------------------------------------------
--           1 Name 1                                       
--           2 Name 2                                       
--           3 Name 3            
    tbl_c AS
        (   Select LEVEL "ID", To_Date('23.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') - LEVEL + 3 "A_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 2 Union All
            Select LEVEL "ID", To_Date('23.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') - LEVEL + 1 "A_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3 
        )
--          ID A_DATE   
--  ---------- ---------
--           1 25-OCT-23
--           2 24-OCT-23
--           1 23-OCT-23
--           2 22-OCT-23
--           3 21-OCT-23
```

results as

```sql
--          ID A_NAME                  A_DATE     
--  ---------- ---------------------- -----------
--           1 Name 1                 25-OCT-23
--           2 Name 2                 24-OCT-23
--           3 Name 3                 21-OCT-23
```

Answer (score 0):

A very clean solution is to use *lateral inline views*:

```
SELECT a.id
      ,b.a_name
      ,c.a_date
  FROM tbl_a a
  LEFT JOIN tbl_b b ON ( b.id = a.id )
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT c.a_date
                        FROM tbl_c c
                       WHERE c.id = a.id
                       ORDER BY a_date DESC
                       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
                    ) c
```

Comment: `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` will behave like an `INNER JOIN` rather than an `OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `OUTER LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_A a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
       ON b.ID = a.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   TABLE_C c
         WHERE  c.id = a.id
         ORDER BY c.datecolumn DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY        -- or FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
      )
      ON (1 = 1)                     -- The join condition is in the `WHERE` clause but
                                     -- an `ON` clause is required for an OUTER JOIN.
```

or use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function (or the `RANK` analytic function if you want the same behaviour as `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_A a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
       ON b.ID = a.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT c.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY c.datecolumn DESC) AS rnk
         FROM   TABLE_C c
      ) c
      ON (c.id = a.id AND c.rnk = 1)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1gY531lt)